IEnumerable to IEntityCollection
I am trying to load a collection using IEntitySource.GetCollection method. I need to have distinct values in this collection so I am trying to use Distinct() method after loading the collection. However, the next method should use an IEntityCollection. So, I need to have this distinct list in an IEntityCollection type.

Step 1 : GetCollection (This return an IentityCollection) Query.From("TestTable")
Step 2 : Fetch distinct values from this collection (Using Distinct() which returns IEnumerable type) Session.Source.GetCollection(qryTest).Distinct()
Step 3 : Do something to cast this object from IEnumerable to IEntityCollection)
Step 4 : Use the IEntityCollection for further operation ats the items under this collection would be of IEntity type.

This object colTest is returned as IEnumerable as Distinct is used, but I need to have this as of type IEntityCollection.
Thanks in advance,
Nutan
I have trid adding Disitnct method to pull all dstinct element from collection, but i need it to be of type IEntityCollection

Post a snippet of the code.

Dim queryDW as Query = Query.From("TestTable").WHere("Order = '1'").OrderBy("OperationDate asc").SelectAll()
DIm col As IentityCollection = Session.Source.GetCollection(queryDW).Distinct()
If I remove Distinct() from the above line, all works fine, but otherwise I need distinct valuee, hence I need to add this method.
